# Reading the same data from stdin through pipe multiple(basically 2 ) times in Java

Tags: java, pipe

I am trying to read data which comes from the the output of another command multiple times.

My command is like this :-

```
cat input.txt | java -Xmx128m abcJavaFile | sort -k1,1 | java -Xmx128m xyzJavaFile inputTextFile > output.txt
```

Now in xyzJavaFile I want to store some data coming from sort commmand in some variables and then again access the pipe output to do something with the same data.

Like this:-

```
BufferedReader consoleInput1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String curDoc1 = null;
while((curDoc1 = consoleInput1.readLine()) != null) {
    //do something here
}

BufferedReader consoleInput2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String curDoc2 = null;
while((curDoc2 = consoleInput2.readLine()) != null) {
    //again do something here
}
```

Comment: You can't.  Save it the first time you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, a pipe streams the data. You can store the data if it is not too big, or write it to a temp file while reading it the first time and use the file to read the data again for the second processing step.

```
BufferedReader consoleInput1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String curDoc1 = null;
File temp = File.createTempFile("data", null);
try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(temp.toPath())) {
    while((curDoc1 = consoleInput1.readLine()) != null) {
        doSomething(curDoc1);
        bw.write(curDoc1 + "\n");
    }
}

BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(temp.toPath());
String curDoc2 = null;
while((curDoc2 = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //again do something here
}
```

Depending of the nature of your computations, it may also be possible to merge the two loops into one.

Comment: my input.txt file is about 1.1gigs and input to xyzJavaFile is about 1 million words each on every line, Even if I use hashmap to store unique words, it won't fit in 128m limit

Comment: That's why I write to disk

Comment: So there is no way to do without storing in file..like just streaming..?

Comment: Yes, what else could it be ? If it is not wholly in memory it is necessarily streamed. It all depends of what you do in your two loops, maybe you could simply have one

Comment: Can you detail the code in your loops then, so that our answers can be useful ?

Comment: sorry for late reply, It is of 100lines of code , can i post it here

Answer (score 1):

If your input isn't super large (quite a bit less than 128m) you can read data once into a memory buffer, then build readers from that buffer as often as you want.

```
// copy input into buffer
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
CharArrayWriter writer = new CharArrayWriter();
char[] transfer = new char[4096];
int count;
while ((count = reader.read(transfer)) != -1) {
    writer.write(transfer, 0, count);
}
char[] buffer = writer.toCharArray();

// use stream from buffer as often as you want
BufferedReader consoleInput1 = new BufferedReader(new CharArrayReader(buffer));
BufferedReader consoleInput2 = new BufferedReader(new CharArrayReader(buffer));
....
```

If it gets too large you can store the data on disk:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("data", ".tmp");
tempFile.deleteOnExit();

// copy input into buffer
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(tempFile)) {
    char[] transfer = new char[4096];
    int count;
    while ((count = reader.read(transfer)) != -1) {
        writer.write(transfer, 0, count);
    }
}
// use stream from buffer as often as you want
BufferedReader consoleInput1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile));
BufferedReader consoleInput2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile));
```

Comment: Isn't it more efficient to use a `BufferedWriter` ?

Comment: @Dici not really. The `transfer` buffer does explicitly what `Buffered???` do under the hood. If you use one you'll end up double copying data from buffers to buffers. Upping the size of `transfer` to like 64k could be beneficial though.

Comment: Apparently the default buffer size is 8k so you will hit the disk less often, which will result (I think) in a faster loop

Comment: @Dici yep, larger buffers are better. Change `transfer`s size as desired and maybe run your own benchmark to find out what the ideal size is. There are also tons of benchmarks on different ways of doing that with java. Like http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/08/file-copy-in-java-benchmark.html . Or if you know that you need to keep data in a file let your command line do it instead of java and run the java on the file instead. `.. | sort > foo.txt && java .. foo.txt` or so

Comment: @Dici oops :) didn't notice